# Push a new commit without previous commit dependencies

Tags: git

I made a commit in my local system and pushed it for review..

Now i want to make another commit and push it and make sure the first one is not a dependency. How can i do that?

Please help me with the commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options. You can simply discard the last commit (you'll lose it and have to use reflog to recover it unless you save the hash):

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Alternatively you can do a soft reset and stash your last commit:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git stash
```

Or you can branch the commit before and work in that branch:

```
git checkout -b newbranch HEAD~1
```

Answer (score 1):

Branches are great for this. You want to make another commit based on the parent of the commit you pushed, so that it doesn't contain its changes.

Say your commit is B and its parent is A. You reset the working copy to commit A (your work won't be lost since it is pushed) by doing

```
git checkout HEAD~
```

`HEAD~` meaning the parent of current branche's commit.

Then make the changes, and commit them to a new branch:

```
git checkout -b other_feature_branch
git commit
```

Comment: Better off doing `git checkout -b new_branch HEAD^`. A hard reset is rarely a good hint to give (**destroys** uncommitted changes, unrecoverable)